# Is there a way to use the JQuery Hide and Show functions on two pages?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want specific images to disappear on a page when I click on a certain image on a different page which is hyperlinked to the second page. I have seen the use of the Hide and Show functions and was wondering if it was possible to say "if this image on this page is clicked then hide these images and show the image that has been clicked"?

```
$("p").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});

$("p").click(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

The Hide and Show functions I have seen are shown above!

If I need to provide anything else, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You could use cookies to do that,

1. Set a cookie on the first page if it's clicked
2. Get the cookie on the other page and hide the image if the cookie is there

Pros:

- you can reset the cookie or make the cookie expire after a specific time
- secure, unless the use shouldn't be able to show the image again

Cons:

- the user can edit the cookies
- the cookies expire (but you can set the expiration to multiple years)

Good JavaScript Tutorials:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Good PHP Tutorials:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

My recommendation is to use PHP so it even works if the user has disabled JavaScript.

Comment: How would I go about setting up the cookies? and would I need to use the above function yeah?

Comment: Page 1:
https://codepen.io/Shanox/pen/dyOJwqL

Page 2:
https://codepen.io/Shanox/pen/MWbrZZr

Comment: Hey, I have tried to implement the cookies thing onto both my pages. When I go onto page 1 and click an image, it takes me to the page 2 but with no images. Happy to provide images of what I have got if needed!

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Try deleting the cookie by typing ```document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });``` into the console and go to the page without clicking the image again. It should be there!

Comment: I've now edited the pen for page 1 if you want to make the image reappear once the user clicks the image again!

Comment: Basically I want the image I click on to show on the next page but not the others? So the images are set on the 2nd page, I just want the one I click on to stay and the others to be hidden. Will this cookies thing do that?

Comment: Ok, yes it will do that.
When you click the image on the first page the image will be hidden on the 2nd page.

Comment: I want all the images that werent clicked to disappear and the one that did get clicked to be shown on page 2

Comment: Oh, I understand. I've edited the pen, tried it on my website and it works!